# $Ax \le b$ when $A$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have the following linear system of inequalities:
$$Ax \le b $$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is not invertible and moreover $\operatorname{Rk}(A)<\operatorname{Rk}(A|b)$. This implies that the corresponding linear system does not have a solution but that doesn't mean that I cannot find solutions for the inequality.

Is there a way to find the set of solutions for this system?

Comment: You can turn the inequalities into equalities by adding slack variables. For instance. if the first equation is $x_1+x_2 \leq 3$, you can add a variable $s_1$ and have the equality $x_1+x_2+s_1=3$.

Comment: In what manner do you want the set of solutions presented? How much more explicit do you want it to be?

Comment: Just throw this into an LP solver (with a dummy objective).